# How to split a two-digit number up in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I need to split a two-digit number up so that I can display them separately. The problem is that mod only works with numbers that are a power of 2. How can this be done?

Comment: I presume you mean a two digit *decimal* number ?

Comment: What do you mean by "split up," and by "two-digit?" Something like turning the number `42` into `4` and `2`?

Comment: I downvoted it because, as I said in my answer, it is both confusing (`$display` is a task name in Verilog, so it is not clear whether your problem is modeling or synthesis) and incorrect (some synthesis tools do support modulo with non-powers of 2.) I will remove the downvote if you clarify (also taking into account the other comments) and correct the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple brute force solution would be to use an if-else block to compare your number to multiples of 10.  The largest multiple of ten that is smaller than your number is the "tens" digit, and the difference is the "ones" digit.

```
if (number >= 90) begin
    tens <= 9;
    ones <= number - 90;
end else if ...
```

That said, this isn't scalable, and giant if-else blocks are generally not good practice.

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.edaboard.com/thread112872.html

> Many synthesis tools don't support
>   integer division/modulus/remainder
>   unless the calculation is trivial,
>   such as division by a power of two. If
>   your value isn't a power of two, then
>   you are probably out of luck.
>
> Maybe you can use another approach
>   such as building your own math module,
>   or using a math core from your
>   software's IP library.
>
> Or maybe you can approximate the
>   division by multiplying by the
>   fraction 1/K instead of dividing by K.
>
> If both operands are small, you could
>   fetch the result from a ROM lookup
>   table.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a simple incrementing value, you should consider [Binary Coded Decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) counters. You need 4 bits per digit but it makes interfacing with 7-segment displays much easier.

```
//BCD counter - I did not test this
reg [3:0] digit_one, digit_two;    
always @(posedge clk)
  begin : led_digits
  if(reset)
    begin
    digit_one <= 0;
    digit_two <= 0;
    end
  else if(increment)
    begin
    //BCD values wrap at 9 
    if(digit_one == 4'd9)
      digit_one <= 0;
    else
      digit_one <= digit_one + 1;

    //Carry when previous digit wraps
    if(digit_one == 4'd9)
      begin
      if(digit_two == 4'd9)
        digit_two <= 0;
      else
        digit_two <= digit_two + 1;
      end
    end
  end
```

If you have some arbitrary decimal value you need to display, then it gets more complicated. GuanoLoco's solution should work for a 2 digit output. A more efficient algorithm exists but the [implementation](http://edda.csie.dyu.edu.tw/course/fpga/Binary2BCD.pdf) is not as straightforward.

Answer (score -1):

Rather confusinq question. When you say "display", I immediately think `$display`, hence modeling and simulation. There are no powers of 2 restrictions on modulo for modeling purposes.

But even if you mean synthesis, it is not true in general that modulo only works with powers of 2. However, doing this is probably not a very good idea, because it would be quite expensive in hardware.

Comment: I'm not trying to use $display. I need to light up some 7-segment LEDs to display the decimal value of a binary number. I have a module which can display a decimal number on one LED. I'm trying to use this module to display a two-digit number, so I need to split up the binary number into two decimal numbers.